# Jquery Isotope PLugin : Custom layout mode: Category rows - how to add a header to each category row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to customize the Isotope jquery plugin David DeSandro but not getting anywhere....

I am trying to add a category name as a header for the Custom Layout : Category Rows

here is a link to the custom layout on David DeSandro's website:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/custom-layout-modes/category-rows.html

So I want it exactly like the example but just have the name of each category above corresponding row.

Is it even possible with Isotope ?

cheers & thanks for your valuable time !

Answer (score 0):

in short, i inserted for each category a div with a header class to the elements, gave that class the style for the header, which is the complete length of the container and some smaller height and put in the div the content for the header.
then simply applied the layoutMode.
*categories* is an object with the category infos.

```
var h = '';
$.each(categories,function(i,v) {
                //insert header row
                if($('.element.'+v.code).length){
                    h = h+'<div class="element category header '+v.type+'" data-type="'+v.type+'" data-category="'+v.code+'"><img src="'+v.icon+'"> '+v.title+'</div>';
                }
            });
            $container.isotope('insert',$(h));
            $container.isotope( {
                sortBy : $(this).attr('data-sort'),
                sortAscending : false,
                layoutMode: categoryRows,
                categoryRows : {
                    gutter : 2
                }
            });
```

i tried also the callback of the insert here, but that seem to flicker more then without.

but you have to think of way more:

- get the header row above the elements when sortAscending is true
- removing the header, when applying another LayouMode (there the missing remove callback hurts, but setTimeout does it)
- dont add the header again, if its already there

im still elobarating, but that would be my approach for now

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but I can't seem to get it to work... Do you build it on the category row layout ? do you only use this in the script tag ? can you explain i bit better ?
Cheers!!!